# How to test a PHP API in a Docker container

Tags: php, docker, phpunit

I have an api built with PHP/Symfony, inside a Docker container. I would like to test it.

To do that :

- first : I enter into my container : docker-compose exec da-invoicing-php sh
- second : I run the test : vendor/bin/simple-phpunit

In my test I have this request :

```
$result = $this->client->request(
        'POST',
        '10.110.167.124:8080/api/v1/course_invoices',
        [
            RequestOptions::HEADERS => [
                'Accept' => 'application/ld+json',
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'Authorization' => "Bearer {$this->token}",
            ],
            RequestOptions::BODY => json_encode([
                'courseInstanceId' => self::COURSE_INSTANCE,
            ]),
        ]
    );
```

As you can see, I request to the endpoint "'10.110.167.124:8080/api/v1.....". It works but I know that I cannot continue like that.

I tried with 'localhost', 'localhost:8080', 'http://localhost', etc... without success. I always have this error :

> GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

So how to do this test inside a container?

### Edit

My docker-compose

```
services:
  da-invoicing-php:
    build:
        context: .
        args:
            GITHUB_TOKEN: 060......2e8b
    container_name: da-invoicing-php
    depends_on:
      - da-invoicing-db
    env_file:
      - .env.local
    # Comment out this volume in production
    volumes:
      - .:/srv/api:rw,cached

  da-invoicing-api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.nginx
    depends_on:
      - da-invoicing-php
    volumes:
      - ./public:/srv/api/public:ro
    environment:
      - INTERNAL_DNS_RESOLVER=127.0.0.11
    ports:
      - "8080:80"

  da-invoicing-db:
    image: postgres:9.6-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=api
      - POSTGRES_USER=api-platform
      # You should definitely change the password in production
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=!ChangeMe!
    ports:
      - "1234:5432"
```

My Dockerfile :

```
    FROM php:7.3-fpm-alpine

RUN apk add --no-cache  \
        git

ARG http_proxy
ARG APCU_VERSION=5.1.17
RUN if [ ! -z $http_proxy ] ; then pear config-set http_proxy $http_proxy; fi \
  && set -xe \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
        $PHPIZE_DEPS \
        icu-dev \
        postgresql-dev \
        libzip-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) \
        intl \
        pdo_pgsql \
        zip \
    && pecl install \
        apcu-${APCU_VERSION} \
    && pecl clear-cache \
    && docker-php-ext-enable --ini-name 20-apcu.ini apcu \
    && docker-php-ext-enable --ini-name 05-opcache.ini opcache \
    && runDeps="$( \
        scanelf --needed --nobanner --format '%n#p' --recursive /usr/local/lib/php/extensions \
            | tr ',' '\n' \
            | sort -u \
            | awk 'system("[ -e /usr/local/lib/" $1 " ]") == 0 { next } { print "so:" $1 }' \
    )" \
    && apk add --no-cache --virtual .api-phpexts-rundeps $runDeps \
    && apk del .build-deps

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Supervisor
RUN apk add --no-cache supervisor
COPY docker/php/supervisor/*.ini /etc/supervisor.d/

ARG XDEBUG=false
ARG XDEBUG_VERSION=2.6.0
RUN if [ "$XDEBUG" != "false" ] ;then \
    set -eux; \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps $PHPIZE_DEPS; \
    pecl install xdebug-$XDEBUG_VERSION; \
    docker-php-ext-enable xdebug; \
    apk del .build-deps; \
fi

# https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-allow-superuser
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1
ENV COMPOSER_NO_INTERACTION=1
ARG GITHUB_TOKEN
RUN composer config -g github-oauth.github.com ${GITHUB_TOKEN}
RUN composer global require "symfony/flex" --prefer-dist --no-progress --no-suggest --classmap-authoritative \
    && composer clear-cache
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/.composer/vendor/bin"

WORKDIR /srv/api

# Build for production
ARG APP_ENV=prod

# Prevent the reinstallation of vendors at every changes in the source code
COPY composer.json composer.lock ./
RUN echo '<?php return [];' > .env.local.php

RUN composer install --prefer-dist --no-dev --no-autoloader --no-scripts --no-progress --no-suggest \
    && composer clear-cache

# copy only specifically what we need
COPY bin bin/
COPY config config/
COPY public public/
COPY src src/
COPY .env ./

RUN set -eux; \
    mkdir -p var/cache var/log var/sessions; \
    composer dump-autoload --classmap-authoritative --no-dev; \
    composer run-script --no-dev post-install-cmd; \
    chmod +x bin/console; sync; \
    chown -R www-data var
    
VOLUME /srv/api/var

COPY docker/php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
COPY docker/php/fpm.d/zz-academy.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/
COPY docker/php/docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint
COPY docker/php/fpm.d/zz-academy.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint

EXPOSE 9000

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint"]
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

Comment: Can you share the Dockerfile? What port did you expose? Also share your run command.

Comment: Looks like your dockers are not linked to eachother. If they were, you could use the name of the API container as the url. `localhost:8080` cannot work because the api isn't running in the current container.

Comment: i see you are using `docker-compose`. Could you add your `docker-compose.yml` in adition to your `Dockerfile` ?

Comment: added 2 files in edit. Thank you.

Comment: You expose port 9000 in your Dockerfile but try to map to port 80 in Compose.

Comment: Thanks Jay. I replaced ports: "8080:80" by "8080:9000" in my docker-compose.yml. I rebuilt my container and made the POST test with localhost:8080/api/v1/course_invoices without success , I still have the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can't use directly localhost in your PHP container it doesn't serve HTTP, it's php-fpm.

You must call the nginx container da-invoicing-api

```
$result = $this->client->request(
    'POST',
    'da-invoicing-api/api/v1/course_invoices',
    [
        RequestOptions::HEADERS => [
            'Accept' => 'application/ld+json',
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'Authorization' => "Bearer {$this->token}",
        ],
        RequestOptions::BODY => json_encode([
            'courseInstanceId' => self::COURSE_INSTANCE,
        ]),
    ]
);
```

Docker-compose [create host alias](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) for each container in your compose file (Other containers on the same network can use the service name).

Comment: Thanks MoiioM . it works fine now with your explanations. Have a nice day.